# How to call a function in the controller from the view using ASP.NET MVC C# Html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a simple connection between the view and the controller. I have a button in the view

```
<button value="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("submit", "Home")'" >Submit</button>
```

and I have the controller function here

```
public ActionResult submit()
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello test");
    return View();
}
```

When I debug it calls the function, but when it goes through it results in an unhandled exception.

I am still new to this and have not found a simple way to call a function on the controller from the view that will not try to change to a new page. Thank you for any help.

Comment: do you have a view called `submit.cshtml`?  Can you provide details on the error you are getting.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `submit` function.  If the breakpoint is hit, the function got called.  Console.Writeline seems a bit odd in this context, and some moving parts that ASP.NET MVC requires seem to be missing.  Check your ASP.NET MVC documentation; make sure your method is set up correctly with the proper attributes.

Comment: I am believe that Url.Action is the wrong approach. I just want the button to call the function in order to do something like change text on a label or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
return View();
```

in controller method you need to be sure that you have a .cshtml view file.
In your case I think you need to add submit.cshtml file.

Comment: Thanks, that does work in making it not error but I was wrong. I just want something that wont change the page but just change something on the current view

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC you need to use Partial View for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely caused because you

A: don't have a view called submit, and since you are not naming a view in the controller return it is looking for a view it cannot find
or

B: you are not returning a view model which the view is expecting,  posting up the exception you are getting will make it easier to help with this!

you will need to use java script to achieve what you want to.  There is no way to call a function in a controller without causing a page refresh, even if you do not return a view, or return the same view it will end up doing a full page refresh.

You need to look into using an asynchronous java script call like the fetch() A.P.I.  this will allow you to trigger methods in the controller and then you can return the results of this method as json, or by rerendering a partial view.  Unless  I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve!